# Expo modules core dependency.platformns.ios must be of type object

Tags: react-native, expo

I just updated to Expo 43.0 in a bare workflow project and followed the guide on how to update the app to also use expo-modules-core. The app runs in dev mode and can compile to both Android and iOS. However, when running react-native-start the following message is shown in the terminal:

```
warn Package expo-modules-core has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: "dependency.platforms.ios" must be of type object
```

Then the metro server starts. I have tried searching for others with similar issues, does anyone know what may be causing this?

I followed this guide: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/

Comment: Got the same problem, Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning is coming from react-native-community autolinking. it looks like the api changed and they don't accept null values anymore, but this is what they still specify in their docs. the behavior you see is expected still - expo-modules-core is and should be ignored by react-native-community autolinking, because it's handled by expo autolinking. so, this won't impact your project and it's a warning caused either by an accidental regression or undocumented change in react-native-community autolinking.

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16085

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is coming from react-native. So for resolving this issue you have to remove the **react-native.config.js** file from **node_modules**

Follow the bellow steps:-

Go to **node_modules/expo-modules-core**

Delete **react-native.config.js**